# How send data from fragment in TabLayout to MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a `TabLayout` with two tabs and a `MainActivity`.
 How can I send data from `fragment1` which placed in `tab1` to `MainActivity`?

Comment: try googling "passing data from fragment to activity" do some effort then edit this post with code if you face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one interface for that. Please check code snippet.

Fragment

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

  public interface onSomeEventListener {
    public void someEvent(String s);
  }

  onSomeEventListener someEventListener;

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
          someEventListener = (onSomeEventListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onSomeEventListener");
        }
  }

  final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, null);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        someEventListener.someEvent("Test text to Fragment1");
      }
    });

    return v;
  }
}
```

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onSomeEventListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Fragment frag2 = new Fragment2();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment2, frag2);
        ft.commit();
    }

  @Override
  public void someEvent(String s) {
      Fragment frag1 = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);
      ((TextView)frag1.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("Text from Fragment 2:" + s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling an activity from a fragment and you want to send data to Activity you can use intents like below:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
    String name = "Transporter";
    intent.putExtra("name", name);
    startActivity(intent);
```

And in your activity you should get the data like this:

```
 try {

         Intent intent = getIntent();
         String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

        } catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```